# Implementing expires headers when using Amazon CDN

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, mod-expires, expires-header

I can't seem to get **expires headers** working with **Amazon CDN** after reading a lot of documentation online.

I have updated my htacess file on the server (I presume this is ignored for those files served by CDN).

I have looked at my CDN origin/behaviours but I am not sure how I'd go about adding expires headers there... or if it's even possible!

**Can anyone suggest how this can be done**?

Comment: `Expires` is deprecated in favor of `Cache-Control`, but CloudFront will simply pass it through if your server returns the `Expires` header.  Did you do a cache invaldation?  If not, CloudFront may be serving the objects from its cache, and has cached them before you changed your server.

Comment: This has now been resolved Michael - you're correct - there was just some propagation time to get it working.